# Git Bundle with LFS

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-bundle

I'm needing to bundle a git repo that we've been using git-lfs on but have run into an issue.

It will bundle up fine but when I come to clone it this error occurs

> Downloading .../Dll's/DotNetZip.dll (458 KB) Error downloading object:
>   .../Dll's/DotNetZip.dll (7dd20a2): Smudge error: Error downloading
>   .../Dll's/DotNetZip.dll
>   (7dd20a2291b05323bba04be4ae656d7635ae5e68a5a6fa2b9f86e27841846a31):
>   batch request: missing protocol:
>   "C:/...bundleName.bundle.git/info/lfs"
>
> Errors logged to C:/.../.git\lfs\logs\20180831T093319.3979074.log Use
>   `git lfs logs last` to view the log. error: external filter 'git-lfs
>   filter-process' failed fatal: ../Dll's/DotNetZip.dll: smudge filter
>   lfs failed warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed. You can
>   inspect what was checked out with 'git status' and retry the checkout
>   with 'git checkout -f HEAD'

I can't seem to find any documentation on how lfs should work with git bundle. All i really need for my lfs file is to store the latest version in the bundle but can't seem to find out where that could be either.

Comment: Thi link https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1755 should help you in someway. From my understanding, there is not a full support in git-lfs of the command bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Got same error in Ubuntu-20.04.1-LTS which still come with an oldish git-lfs version 2.9.

The error is mentioned in [github.com/git-lfs](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3964) and a fix is in git-lfs 2.10 or newer (at this time latest version is 2.13.2) and to install it these steps should be followed (see also [wiki](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Installation#installing)):

```
sudo apt install curl
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install git-lfs
git lfs install
git clone git@bitbucket.org:project/repo.git --recursive
cd repo/
git lfs install
git checkout some_branch
```

The error disappeared after that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `git bundle` isn't supported by `git-lfs`. However, with recent versions of `git-lfs` you can use local "bare" type git repos instead of a web-based repo manager like GitHub or GitLab.

To create a "bundle" of a git repo including its lfs data from GitHub using a local bare repo:

First, clone the repo from GitHub and fetch everything:

```
git clone https://github.com/some-user/lfs-repo
cd lfs-repo
git fetch --all
git fetch --tags
git lfs install
git lfs fetch --all
```

Then create a new bare repo:

```
cd ..
mkdir bare-repo
cd bare-repo
git init --bare
```

Then add the new bare repo as a remote to your cloned repo and push everything to it:

```
cd ../lfs-repo
git remote add bare file://$(pwd)/../bare-repo
git push --all bare
git push --tags bare
git lfs push --all bare
```

Now you have all the data (including the lfs data) in your `bare-repo`. You can zip it now:

```
cd ..
tar -czvf bundle.tar.gz bare-repo
```

If you want to retrieve the data from the "bundle", simply copy the file to the desired host, extract it and clone from it using the `file://` URL.

References: [Link1](https://poweruser.blog/git-lfs-how-to-work-offline-how-to-archive-bundle-a-lfs-repo-c5ff5f10cc86), [Link2](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1755#issuecomment-968986113)